# Empty Address when using Truffle Debug

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-invocation, ganache, truffle-contract

I currently have a local chain with Ganache. Say I have two contracts written in Solidity:

```
Foo_v0_0_1.sol
Bar_v0_0_1.sol
```

In the code for my smart contract `Foo_v0_0_1`, I have the following:

```
import "./Bar_v0_0_1.sol";

Bar_v0_0_1 private _bar;

...

function callBar() external {
    _bar.func(msg.sender); // <-- EXECUTION FAILS HERE
}
```

I deploy these contracts and attempt the `callBar` RPC call. This transaction fails on the internal call to the `_bar` contract. I open this transaction with `truffle debug <tx_hash>`, and step to the line where the transaction fails. When I print out the state and local variables, I see this in the output:

```
Contract variables:
    _bar: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 of unknown class
```

My question: Why is this variable coming up as all zeroes? Is it an issue with how I deployed my contracts? Is it an issue with the truffle debugger not being able to correctly find the contract?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Bar_v0_0_1 private _bar;` - where is this variable initialized? Did you expect it to automatically attain some value???

Comment: The fact that Truffle keeps record of all the contracts that you deploy, doesn't mean that these deployed contracts have any knowledge of each other.